# jquery old code, where is the mistake?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this page:

[Page](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/)

and its exactly what i was looking. Now i copied the code and it dosent work.

```js
$(function() {
    
    
    
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
        
        $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });
        
        $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

```html
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

i changed the **.live()** event(?) to **.on()**, but i cant remove the input fields. Maybe someone of you see the mistake, because im new in jquery.

Comment: it works http://jsfiddle.net/q9c5n324/, did you add a JQuery library in your site?

Comment: That code is bad anyway; it creates an invalid DOM by re-using "id" values.

Comment: Yes i added a library. Press on the "remove" button, then you will see my problem :P @Pointy Ok then i will write it new in a few days when im far enough ^^

Comment: signature for `on()` is different than `live()` when delegating events ... see docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element doesn't exist on load, so it has to be delegated

```
  `$(selector).on('click', 'newelement', function() . . .
```

Also use a class rather than ID for the dynamically created item or else you will duplicate IDs.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/q9c5n324/2/)